# Connect to docker postgresql from mac without internet

Tags: postgresql, docker

I use docker-compose up to start postgresql container.

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: javauser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: javapass
      POSTGRES_DB: javadb
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
```

From my mac, I start java app

```
java -jar target/dummy.wallet-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar server DummyWallet.yaml
```

It uses DB connection configuration as

```
database:
  # the name of your JDBC driver
  driverClass: org.postgresql.Driver

  # the username
  user: xxx

  # the password
  password: xxx

  # the JDBC URL
  url: jdbc:postgresql://0.0.0.0/xx
```

When my mac is connected to internet, connection works just fine.
When my mac is NOT connected to internet, java throws no route to host error.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
```

I tried 127.0.0.1 and container name. Doesn’t work. How do I fix this?

Comment: have you tried adding `name: db` to your `docker-compose.yml`, then connect with container name?  Other option to try is to create a network and hard-code the IP addresses for both containers

Comment: yes and yes. I tried the IP address it still gives network unreachable..